# Parcel crashing if Google's Pub/Sub library is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, parcel

I'm using Parcel to build the JS code for a simple front-end I use to test some stuff, and today I tried using Google's Pub/Sub Node.js client on it, did the proper installation, but it won't build if the `require('@google-cloud/pubsub')` is present. when I try `npx parcel build home.html --public-url /dist` I get:

```
  Could not load source file "../../src/index.ts" in source map of "node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/index.js".
  Could not load source file "../../src/index.ts" in source map of "node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/index.js".
  Could not load source file "../../src/subscriber.ts" in source map of "node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/subscriber.js".
  Could not load existing sourcemap of "node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js".
  Could not load source file "../../src/fallback.ts" in source map of "node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.js".
  Could not load source file "../../src/message-stream.ts" in source map of "node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/message-stream.js".
  Could not load existing sourcemap of "node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/transporters.js".
  Could not load existing sourcemap of "node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js".
  Could not load source file "../../src/index.ts" in source map of "node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js".
  Could not load existing sourcemap of "node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js".
  Could not load source file "../../src/gaxios.ts" in source map of "node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js".
  Could not load existing sourcemap of "node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js".
  Could not load source file "../src/index.ts" in source map of "node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js".
  Could not load source file "../src/agent.ts" in source map of "node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js".
  /Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js: /Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js: Property name expected type of string but got null
    at validate (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:160:13)
    at Object.validate (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:229:7)
    at validateField (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:24:9)
    at validate (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:3)
    at builder (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/builder.js:38:27)
    at Object.identifier (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/generated/index.js:340:31)
    at /Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/hoist.js:32:29
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at varDeclToExpr (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/hoist.js:29:23)
    at exit (/Users/.../src/webserver/templates/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/hoist.js:51:20)
```

As it will be clear to most, my JS knowledge is very limited, the JS code was not implemented by me, I only make occasional changes to it. I'm pretty much stuck here. The only reference I could find of a similar problem was in [this](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/576) GitHub issue. What should I try?

Comment: you should first ```npm install @google-cloud/pubsub```.  If your knowledge is limited, you should get the person who implement this to resolve the issues.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial he rests in peace. And yeah, I did install it first thing. Thanks!